# High Energy Metal Halide Bulb Heat?

Tags: power-supply, power, temperature, heat, fan

I am building a custom box from wood (around 14 inches by 10 inches by 10 inches) to encase 3 high energy Metal Halide Bulbs (400+ watt each). The box will be opened and closed intermittently, automatically. It will be closed for a maximum of 60 minutes straight. When the box is closed, the lights will remain on.

This will of course generate a lot of heat when the box is closed and I understand that I need to some take precautions to filter out the heat from the box.

Right now I can think of having a few holes in the back of the box and using a powerful fan to "drain" out the heat.

Furthermore, I am thinking of treating the walls of the box with a flame proof liquid.

Are there any other / more efficient ways to drain the heat from within the box?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1200 watts is a lot of heat - there are a lot of room heaters that put out that much heat. You will need fan that can move a lot of air and some sort of overheat protection to do what you are thinking of doing.

Any chance that you could put the bulbs outside the box and use a transparent side?

Comment: How much heat will 1200 watts generate over a 60 min period? The bulbs cannot be placed outside the box as the box is meant to "contain" all light when it is closed..

Comment: What about all the light 'leaking out' through the fan holes ... ?

Comment: I thought of using a duct fan so there are no holes